# Switching default locale of Orgmode-generated output

Tags: org-mode

Suggestions for a better title are welcome.

Essentially, I want to use Org to write in Ukrainian.

Yet, when I export it (pdf or odt) I get:

> Figure 1: Контекстна діаграма

How can I customize Emacs to get the output, so that I could get Рисунок written instead of Figure ?:

> Рисунок 1: Контекстна діаграма

or, to go even further, to get:

> Рисунок 1 - Контекстна діаграма

True, I can do manual "replace all" in LibreOffice, but this is inconvenient and does not account for other cases when I need to influence Org export behavior.
I am fairly new to Org mode (haven't read the whole manual yet), but which support does Org provide for other languages / locales?

Could you point me to where this is documented?

Comment: `#+LANGUAGE: uk` is part of the solution. The other part is to make sure that `org-export-dictionary` contains all the right entries: a cursory look shows e.g. that the "Figure" translation is missing.  Once you have it done to your satisfaction, consider submitting a patch to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry to `org-export-dictionary`.

Down below you see a list of entries for russian language.  (I chose russian because the ukrainian word for figure--Рисунок--matches with  the russian word for it).

If you are happy with existing russian entries, the easiest way out for you will be to use `#+LANGUAGE: ru`.

```lisp
(("Author" 
  :html "&#1040;&#1074;&#1090;&#1086;&#1088;" 
  :utf-8 "Автор")
 ("Continued from previous page" 
  :html "(&#1055;&#1088;&#1086;&#1076;&#1086;&#1083;&#1078;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;)" 
  :utf-8 "(Продолжение)")
 ("Continued on next page" 
  :html "(&#1055;&#1088;&#1086;&#1076;&#1086;&#1083;&#1078;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077; &#1089;&#1083;&#1077;&#1076;&#1091;&#1077;&#1090;)" 
  :utf-8 "(Продолжение следует)")
 ("Created")
 ("Date" 
  :html "&#1044;&#1072;&#1090;&#1072;" 
  :utf-8 "Дата")
 ("Equation" 
  :html "&#1059;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1085;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;" 
  :utf-8 "Уравнение")
 ("Figure" 
  :html "&#1056;&#1080;&#1089;&#1091;&#1085;&#1086;&#1082;" 
  :utf-8 "Рисунок")
 ("Figure %d:" 
  :html "&#1056;&#1080;&#1089;. %d.:" 
  :utf-8 "Рис. %d.:")
 ("Footnotes" 
  :html "&#1057;&#1085;&#1086;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;" 
  :utf-8 "Сноски")
 ("List of Listings" 
  :html "&#1057;&#1087;&#1080;&#1089;&#1086;&#1082; &#1088;&#1072;&#1089;&#1087;&#1077;&#1095;&#1072;&#1090;&#1086;&#1082;" 
  :utf-8 "Список распечаток")
 ("List of Tables" 
  :html "&#1057;&#1087;&#1080;&#1089;&#1086;&#1082; &#1090;&#1072;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;" 
  :utf-8 "Список таблиц")
 ("Listing" 
  :html "&#1056;&#1072;&#1089;&#1087;&#1077;&#1095;&#1072;&#1090;&#1082;&#1072;" 
  :utf-8 "Распечатка")
 ("Listing %d:" 
  :html "&#1056;&#1072;&#1089;&#1087;&#1077;&#1095;&#1072;&#1090;&#1082;&#1072; %d.:" 
  :utf-8 "Распечатка %d.:")
 ("References")
 ("See figure %s")
 ("See listing %s")
 ("See section %s" 
  :html "&#1057;&#1084;. &#1088;&#1072;&#1079;&#1076;&#1077;&#1083; %s" 
  :utf-8 "См. раздел %s")
 ("See table %s")
 ("Table" 
  :html "&#1058;&#1072;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072;" 
  :utf-8 "Таблица")
 ("Table %d:" 
  :html "&#1058;&#1072;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072; %d.:" 
  :utf-8 "Таблица %d.:")
 ("Table of Contents" 
  :html "&#1057;&#1086;&#1076;&#1077;&#1088;&#1078;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;" 
  :utf-8 "Содержание")
 ("Unknown reference" 
  :html "&#1053;&#1077;&#1080;&#1079;&#1074;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;&#1085;&#1072;&#1103; &#1089;&#1089;&#1099;&#1083;&#1082;&#1072;" 
  :utf-8 "Неизвестная ссылка"))
```

I generated the above list using

```lisp
(progn
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (let ((lang "ru"))
    (cl-loop for (string . entry) in (cdr org-export-dictionary)
         collect (cons string (assoc-default lang entry)))))
```

Here is a list of English strings that may have to be translated to ukraininan

```lisp
(
 "Author"
 "Continued from previous page"
 "Continued on next page"
 "Created"
 "Date"
 "Equation"
 "Figure"
 "Figure %d:"
 "Footnotes"
 "List of Listings"
 "List of Tables"
 "Listing"
 "Listing %d:"
 "References"
 "See figure %s"
 "See listing %s"
 "See section %s"
 "See table %s"
 "Table"
 "Table %d:"
 "Table of Contents"
 "Unknown reference"
 )
```

I generated above list with

```lisp
(progn
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (cl-loop for (string . entry) in (cdr org-export-dictionary)
       collect string))
```

The code you are looking for is in `ox.el`. See https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/49364f904b793513112fb8f71dd6b7f6274171cf/lisp/ox.el#L5720

If you are uncomfortable with Emacs Lisp, no need to worry.  You can proceed intuitively.

Do the following

1. `C-h v org-export-dictionary`.  And click on `ox.el` link in the resulting help buffer.
2. Copy-paste the "ru" lines and modify the russian strings to ukranian ones, and remembering to  replace "ru" with "uk".  (You may have to change the `read-only` status of `ox.el` file.).  To keep things simpler, you don't have to add new ukraininan lines.  Just modify the russian strings to your taste.
3. Once you have done that do `M-x load-library ox.el`.
4. Export your file.
5. If you are happy with results, you can do `C-x C-f ox.el` and `M-x byte-compile-file`, and then restart Emacs.

If you provide me ukrainian translation for above English strings, I can give you a  Elisp recipe for modifying `org-export-dictionary` with ukrainian entries.  You can add this recipe to your `.emacs`.

Regarding using a hyphen instead of a colon in captions, I *believe*--I haven't looked at the code.  The docstring of the variable is not that helpful--you need to alter the first entry in `org-export-dictionary` or provide a ukrainian one for it.

```lisp
("%e %n: %c"
 ("fr":default "%e %n : %c"
  :html "%e&nbsp;%n&nbsp;: %c"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  recipe for adding a custom language.

```lisp
(defun org-export-dictionary--add-language (lang data)
  (unless (boundp 'org-export-dictionary)
    (require 'ox))
  (cl-loop for (string . entry) in data do
       (let ((current-entry (assoc string org-export-dictionary))
         (new-entry (when entry (cons lang (if (stringp entry) (list :default entry) entry)))))
         (when (and new-entry current-entry)
           (nconc (cdr current-entry) (list new-entry))))))
```

Here I add a custom  language called `custom2`.  The translation strings here are quite elaborate.

```lisp
(org-export-dictionary--add-language
 "custom2"
 '(("%e %n: %c" :default "%e %n : %c" :html "%e&nbsp;%n&nbsp;: %c")
   ("junk" :default "test")
   ("Author" :default "Auteur")
   ("Continued from previous page" :default "Suite de la page précédente")
   ("Continued on next page" :default "Suite page suivante")
   ("Created")
   ("Date")
   ("Equation" :ascii "Equation" :default "Équation")
   ("Figure")
   ("Figure %d:" :default "Figure %d :" :html "Figure&nbsp;%d&nbsp;:")
   ("Footnotes" :default "Notes de bas de page")
   ("List of Listings" :default "Liste des programmes")
   ("List of Tables" :default "Liste des tableaux")
   ("Listing" :default "Programme" :html "Programme")
   ("Listing %d:" :default "Programme %d :" :html "Programme&nbsp;%d&nbsp;:")
   ("References" :ascii "References" :default "Références")
   ("See figure %s" :default "cf. figure %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;figure&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~figure~%s")
   ("See listing %s" :default "cf. programme %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;programme&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~programme~%s")
   ("See section %s" :default "cf. section %s")
   ("See table %s" :default "cf. tableau %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;tableau&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~tableau~%s")
   ("Table" :default "Tableau")
   ("Table %d:" :default "Tableau %d :")
   ("Table of Contents" :ascii "Sommaire" :default "Table des matières")
   ("Unknown reference" :ascii "Destination inconnue" :default "Référence inconnue")))
```

Here I add a custom language called `"custom"`.  The translation strings are simple.  The snippet below is what you want to use.  Replace, `"custom"` with `"uk"` and `"FIGURE"` with `"Рисунок"`.  Add translations for other entries.

```lisp
(org-export-dictionary--add-language
 "custom"
 '(("%e %n: %c"                         . "%e %n - %c")
   ("Author"                            . "AUTHOR")
   ("Continued from previous page"      . "CONTINUED FROM PREVIOUS PAGE")
   ("Continued on next page"            . "CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE")
   ("Created"                           . "CREATED")
   ("Date"                              . "DATE")
   ("Equation"                          . "EQUATION")
   ("Figure"                            . "FIGURE")
   ("Figure %d:"                        . "FIGURE %d:")
   ("Footnotes"                         . "FOOTNOTES")
   ("List of Listings"                  . "LIST OF LISTINGS")
   ("List of Tables"                    . "LIST OF TABLES")
   ("Listing"                           . "LISTING")
   ("Listing %d:"                       . "LISTING %d:")
   ("References"                        . "REFERENCES")
   ("See figure %s"                     . "SEE FIGURE %s")
   ("See listing %s"                    . "SEE LISTING %s")
   ("See section %s"                    . "SEE SECTION %s")
   ("See table %s"                      . "SEE TABLE %s")
   ("Table"                             . "TABLE")
   ("Table %d:"                         . "TABLE %d:")
   ("Table of Contents"                 . "TABLE OF CONTENTS")
   ("Unknown reference"                 . "UNKNOWN REFERENCE"))
 )
```

For your specific query, here is the snippet in it's simplest form.

I obtained this snippet by replacing `"custom"` above with `"uk"`, `"FIGURE"` with `"Рисунок"` and `"%e %n: %c"` with `"%e %n - %c"`.  I have also removed other entries you(?) don' care about. Note that `colon` is replaced with `hyphen` in the caption format.

```lisp
(org-export-dictionary--add-language
 "uk"
 '(("%e %n: %c"                         . "%e %n - %c")
   ("Figure"                            . "Рисунок"))
 )
```

Now when I export this snippet, I get the desired behaviour in ODT export.

```
#+LANGUAGE: uk
# #+LANGUAGE: custom

This is some text

#+CAPTION: My Profile Photo
[[./photo.png]]

#+CAPTION: My Test Scores
| Physics   | 50 |
| Chemistry |  70 |
```

For the sake of completion, here is a list of strings used *exclusively* by ODT exporter.

```lisp
(delete-dups
 `("Table of Contents"
   ;; List of CATEGORY-NAMEs
   ,@(cl-loop for x in org-odt-category-map-alist collect (nth  3 x))
   ;; List of format specifiers in LABEL-STYLEs
   ,@(apply 'append (cl-loop for label-style in
                 (cl-loop for x in org-odt-category-map-alist
                      collect (nth  2 x))
                 collect (list (nth 1 (assoc-string label-style org-odt-label-styles t))
                       (nth 3 (assoc-string label-style org-odt-label-styles t)))))))
```

which gives the following list

```
("Table of Contents" "Table" "Figure" "Equation" "Listing" "%e %n: %c" "%n" "%c" "(%n)")
```

FWIW, ODT uses `:utf-8` entries for translation.

---

*A word of caution regarding `org-export-dictionary--add-language`*: This will work when adding a *new* language.  But you may run in to problems when you want to *override* the entries for a *existing* language or you want to *augment* an existing entry for a language.  Read on for what this comments means ...

This is what the snippet does to value of `org-export-dictionary`

```
--- a.el    2021-03-27 13:52:11.108743913 +0530
+++ b.el    2021-03-27 13:52:47.721764029 +0530
@@ -1,5 +1,8 @@
 (("%e %n: %c"
-  ("fr" :default "%e %n : %c" :html "%e&nbsp;%n&nbsp;: %c"))
+  ("fr" :default "%e %n : %c" :html "%e&nbsp;%n&nbsp;: %c")
+  ("custom2" :default "%e %n : %c" :html "%e&nbsp;%n&nbsp;: %c")
+  ("custom" :default "%e %n - %c")
+  ("uk" :default "%e %n - %c"))
  ("Author"
   ("ar" :default "تأليف")
   ("ca" :default "Autor")
@@ -27,7 +30,9 @@
   ("sv" :html "F&ouml;rfattare")
   ("uk" :html "&#1040;&#1074;&#1090;&#1086;&#1088;" :utf-8 "Автор")
   ("zh-CN" :html "&#20316;&#32773;" :utf-8 "作者")
-  ("zh-TW" :html "&#20316;&#32773;" :utf-8 "作者"))
+  ("zh-TW" :html "&#20316;&#32773;" :utf-8 "作者")
+  ("custom2" :default "Auteur")
+  ("custom" :default "AUTHOR"))
  ("Continued from previous page"
   ("ar" :default "تتمة الصفحة السابقة")
   ("cs" :default "Pokračování z předchozí strany")
@@ -41,7 +46,9 @@
   ("pt_BR" :html "Continua&ccedil;&atilde;o da p&aacute;gina anterior" :ascii "Continuacao da pagina anterior" :default "Continuação da página anterior")
   ("ro" :default "Continuare de pe pagina precedentă")
   ("ru" :html "(&#1055;&#1088;&#1086;&#1076;&#1086;&#1083;&#1078;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;)" :utf-8 "(Продолжение)")
-  ("sl" :default "Nadaljevanje s prejšnje strani"))
+  ("sl" :default "Nadaljevanje s prejšnje strani")
+  ("custom2" :default "Suite de la page précédente")
+  ("custom" :default "CONTINUED FROM PREVIOUS PAGE"))
  ("Continued on next page"
   ("ar" :default "التتمة في الصفحة التالية")
   ("cs" :default "Pokračuje na další stránce")
@@ -55,13 +62,16 @@
   ("pt_BR" :html "Continua na pr&oacute;xima p&aacute;gina" :ascii "Continua na proxima pagina" :default "Continua na próxima página")
   ("ro" :default "Continuare pe pagina următoare")
   ("ru" :html "(&#1055;&#1088;&#1086;&#1076;&#1086;&#1083;&#1078;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077; &#1089;&#1083;&#1077;&#1076;&#1091;&#1077;&#1090;)" :utf-8 "(Продолжение следует)")
-  ("sl" :default "Nadaljevanje na naslednji strani"))
+  ("sl" :default "Nadaljevanje na naslednji strani")
+  ("custom2" :default "Suite page suivante")
+  ("custom" :default "CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE"))
  ("Created"
   ("cs" :default "Vytvořeno")
   ("nl" :default "Gemaakt op")
   ("pt_BR" :default "Criado em")
   ("ro" :default "Creat")
-  ("sl" :default "Ustvarjeno"))
+  ("sl" :default "Ustvarjeno")
+  ("custom" :default "CREATED"))
  ("Date"
   ("ar" :default "بتاريخ")
   ("ca" :default "Data")
@@ -88,7 +98,8 @@
   ("sv" :default "Datum")
   ("uk" :html "&#1044;&#1072;&#1090;&#1072;" :utf-8 "Дата")
   ("zh-CN" :html "&#26085;&#26399;" :utf-8 "日期")
-  ("zh-TW" :html "&#26085;&#26399;" :utf-8 "日期"))
+  ("zh-TW" :html "&#26085;&#26399;" :utf-8 "日期")
+  ("custom" :default "DATE"))
  ("Equation"
   ("ar" :default "معادلة")
   ("cs" :default "Rovnice")
@@ -108,7 +119,9 @@
   ("ru" :html "&#1059;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1085;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;" :utf-8 "Уравнение")
   ("sl" :default "Enačba")
   ("sv" :default "Ekvation")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#26041;&#31243;" :utf-8 "方程"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#26041;&#31243;" :utf-8 "方程")
+  ("custom2" :ascii "Equation" :default "Équation")
+  ("custom" :default "EQUATION"))
  ("Figure"
   ("ar" :default "شكل")
   ("cs" :default "Obrázek")
@@ -127,7 +140,9 @@
   ("ro" :default "Imaginea")
   ("ru" :html "&#1056;&#1080;&#1089;&#1091;&#1085;&#1086;&#1082;" :utf-8 "Рисунок")
   ("sv" :default "Illustration")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#22270;" :utf-8 "图"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#22270;" :utf-8 "图")
+  ("custom" :default "FIGURE")
+  ("uk" :default "Рисунок"))
  ("Figure %d:"
   ("ar" :default "شكل %d:")
   ("cs" :default "Obrázek %d:")
@@ -148,7 +163,9 @@
   ("ru" :html "&#1056;&#1080;&#1089;. %d.:" :utf-8 "Рис. %d.:")
   ("sl" :default "Slika %d")
   ("sv" :default "Illustration %d")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#22270;%d&nbsp;" :utf-8 "图%d "))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#22270;%d&nbsp;" :utf-8 "图%d ")
+  ("custom2" :default "Figure %d :" :html "Figure&nbsp;%d&nbsp;:")
+  ("custom" :default "FIGURE %d:"))
  ("Footnotes"
   ("ar" :default "الهوامش")
   ("ca" :html "Peus de p&agrave;gina")
@@ -176,7 +193,9 @@
   ("sv" :default "Fotnoter")
   ("uk" :html "&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1084;&#1110;&#1090;&#1082;&#1080;" :utf-8 "Примітки")
   ("zh-CN" :html "&#33050;&#27880;" :utf-8 "脚注")
-  ("zh-TW" :html "&#33139;&#35387;" :utf-8 "腳註"))
+  ("zh-TW" :html "&#33139;&#35387;" :utf-8 "腳註")
+  ("custom2" :default "Notes de bas de page")
+  ("custom" :default "FOOTNOTES"))
  ("List of Listings"
   ("ar" :default "قائمة بالبرامج")
   ("cs" :default "Seznam programů")
@@ -192,7 +211,9 @@
   ("pt_BR" :html "&Iacute;ndice de Listagens" :default "Índice de Listagens" :ascii "Indice de Listagens")
   ("ru" :html "&#1057;&#1087;&#1080;&#1089;&#1086;&#1082; &#1088;&#1072;&#1089;&#1087;&#1077;&#1095;&#1072;&#1090;&#1086;&#1082;" :utf-8 "Список распечаток")
   ("sl" :default "Seznam programskih izpisov")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#20195;&#30721;&#30446;&#24405;" :utf-8 "代码目录"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#20195;&#30721;&#30446;&#24405;" :utf-8 "代码目录")
+  ("custom2" :default "Liste des programmes")
+  ("custom" :default "LIST OF LISTINGS"))
  ("List of Tables"
   ("ar" :default "قائمة بالجداول")
   ("cs" :default "Seznam tabulek")
@@ -213,7 +234,9 @@
   ("ru" :html "&#1057;&#1087;&#1080;&#1089;&#1086;&#1082; &#1090;&#1072;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;" :utf-8 "Список таблиц")
   ("sl" :default "Seznam tabel")
   ("sv" :default "Tabeller")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#34920;&#26684;&#30446;&#24405;" :utf-8 "表格目录"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#34920;&#26684;&#30446;&#24405;" :utf-8 "表格目录")
+  ("custom2" :default "Liste des tableaux")
+  ("custom" :default "LIST OF TABLES"))
  ("Listing"
   ("ar" :default "برنامج")
   ("cs" :default "Program")
@@ -231,7 +254,9 @@
   ("ro" :default "Lista")
   ("ru" :html "&#1056;&#1072;&#1089;&#1087;&#1077;&#1095;&#1072;&#1090;&#1082;&#1072;" :utf-8 "Распечатка")
   ("sl" :default "Izpis programa")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#20195;&#30721;" :utf-8 "代码"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#20195;&#30721;" :utf-8 "代码")
+  ("custom2" :default "Programme" :html "Programme")
+  ("custom" :default "LISTING"))
  ("Listing %d:"
   ("ar" :default "برنامج %d:")
   ("cs" :default "Program %d:")
@@ -249,7 +274,9 @@
   ("pt_BR" :default "Listagem %d:")
   ("ru" :html "&#1056;&#1072;&#1089;&#1087;&#1077;&#1095;&#1072;&#1090;&#1082;&#1072; %d.:" :utf-8 "Распечатка %d.:")
   ("sl" :default "Izpis programa %d")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#20195;&#30721;%d&nbsp;" :utf-8 "代码%d "))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#20195;&#30721;%d&nbsp;" :utf-8 "代码%d ")
+  ("custom2" :default "Programme %d :" :html "Programme&nbsp;%d&nbsp;:")
+  ("custom" :default "LISTING %d:"))
  ("References"
   ("ar" :default "المراجع")
   ("cs" :default "Reference")
@@ -260,7 +287,9 @@
   ("nl" :default "Bronverwijzingen")
   ("pt_BR" :html "Refer&ecirc;ncias" :default "Referências" :ascii "Referencias")
   ("ro" :default "Bibliografie")
-  ("sl" :default "Reference"))
+  ("sl" :default "Reference")
+  ("custom2" :ascii "References" :default "Références")
+  ("custom" :default "REFERENCES"))
  ("See figure %s"
   ("cs" :default "Viz obrázek %s")
   ("fr" :default "cf. figure %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;figure&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~figure~%s")
@@ -268,14 +297,18 @@
   ("nl" :default "Zie figuur %s" :html "Zie figuur&nbsp;%s" :latex "Zie figuur~%s")
   ("pt_BR" :default "Veja a figura %s")
   ("ro" :default "Vezi figura %s")
-  ("sl" :default "Glej sliko %s"))
+  ("sl" :default "Glej sliko %s")
+  ("custom2" :default "cf. figure %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;figure&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~figure~%s")
+  ("custom" :default "SEE FIGURE %s"))
  ("See listing %s"
   ("cs" :default "Viz program %s")
   ("fr" :default "cf. programme %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;programme&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~programme~%s")
   ("nl" :default "Zie programma %s" :html "Zie programma&nbsp;%s" :latex "Zie programma~%s")
   ("pt_BR" :default "Veja a listagem %s")
   ("ro" :default "Vezi tabelul %s")
-  ("sl" :default "Glej izpis programa %s"))
+  ("sl" :default "Glej izpis programa %s")
+  ("custom2" :default "cf. programme %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;programme&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~programme~%s")
+  ("custom" :default "SEE LISTING %s"))
  ("See section %s"
   ("ar" :default "انظر قسم %s")
   ("cs" :default "Viz sekce %s")
@@ -291,7 +324,9 @@
   ("ro" :default "Vezi secțiunea %s")
   ("ru" :html "&#1057;&#1084;. &#1088;&#1072;&#1079;&#1076;&#1077;&#1083; %s" :utf-8 "См. раздел %s")
   ("sl" :default "Glej poglavje %d")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#21442;&#35265;&#31532;%s&#33410;" :utf-8 "参见第%s节"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#21442;&#35265;&#31532;%s&#33410;" :utf-8 "参见第%s节")
+  ("custom2" :default "cf. section %s")
+  ("custom" :default "SEE SECTION %s"))
  ("See table %s"
   ("cs" :default "Viz tabulka %s")
   ("fr" :default "cf. tableau %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;tableau&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~tableau~%s")
@@ -299,7 +334,9 @@
   ("nl" :default "Zie tabel %s" :html "Zie tabel&nbsp;%s" :latex "Zie tabel~%s")
   ("pt_BR" :default "Veja a tabela %s")
   ("ro" :default "Vezi tabelul %s")
-  ("sl" :default "Glej tabelo %s"))
+  ("sl" :default "Glej tabelo %s")
+  ("custom2" :default "cf. tableau %s" :html "cf.&nbsp;tableau&nbsp;%s" :latex "cf.~tableau~%s")
+  ("custom" :default "SEE TABLE %s"))
  ("Table"
   ("ar" :default "جدول")
   ("cs" :default "Tabulka")
@@ -314,7 +351,9 @@
   ("pt_BR" :default "Tabela")
   ("ro" :default "Tabel")
   ("ru" :html "&#1058;&#1072;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072;" :utf-8 "Таблица")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#34920;" :utf-8 "表"))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#34920;" :utf-8 "表")
+  ("custom2" :default "Tableau")
+  ("custom" :default "TABLE"))
  ("Table %d:"
   ("ar" :default "جدول %d:")
   ("cs" :default "Tabulka %d:")
@@ -335,7 +374,9 @@
   ("ru" :html "&#1058;&#1072;&#1073;&#1083;&#1080;&#1094;&#1072; %d.:" :utf-8 "Таблица %d.:")
   ("sl" :default "Tabela %d")
   ("sv" :default "Tabell %d")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#34920;%d&nbsp;" :utf-8 "表%d "))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#34920;%d&nbsp;" :utf-8 "表%d ")
+  ("custom2" :default "Tableau %d :")
+  ("custom" :default "TABLE %d:"))
  ("Table of Contents"
   ("ar" :default "قائمة المحتويات")
   ("ca" :html "&Iacute;ndex")
@@ -363,7 +404,9 @@
   ("sv" :html "Inneh&aring;ll")
   ("uk" :html "&#1047;&#1084;&#1110;&#1089;&#1090;" :utf-8 "Зміст")
   ("zh-CN" :html "&#30446;&#24405;" :utf-8 "目录")
-  ("zh-TW" :html "&#30446;&#37636;" :utf-8 "目錄"))
+  ("zh-TW" :html "&#30446;&#37636;" :utf-8 "目錄")
+  ("custom2" :ascii "Sommaire" :default "Table des matières")
+  ("custom" :default "TABLE OF CONTENTS"))
  ("Unknown reference"
   ("ar" :default "مرجع غير معرّف")
   ("da" :default "ukendt reference")
@@ -378,4 +421,6 @@
   ("ro" :default "Referință necunoscută")
   ("ru" :html "&#1053;&#1077;&#1080;&#1079;&#1074;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;&#1085;&#1072;&#1103; &#1089;&#1089;&#1099;&#1083;&#1082;&#1072;" :utf-8 "Неизвестная ссылка")
   ("sl" :default "Neznana referenca")
-  ("zh-CN" :html "&#26410;&#30693;&#24341;&#29992;" :utf-8 "未知引用")))
+  ("zh-CN" :html "&#26410;&#30693;&#24341;&#29992;" :utf-8 "未知引用")
+  ("custom2" :ascii "Destination inconnue" :default "Référence inconnue")
+  ("custom" :default "UNKNOWN REFERENCE")))
```

As you can see from the diff above,

1. The snippet  *appends* new entries.
2. It doesn't merge the plist values for a language.  In the diff above, you  can see that there are *already* some entries for `"uk"` language.

(1) and (2) will make the snippet *not work* under certain circumstances.